Shoudn’t the obscurantism of the supernatural automatically deem it extremely implausible?
Suppose that one asked you to consider the plausibility of a functioning iPhone 14 forming by complete chance (i.e. without design). As far as I understand, this is actually possible, according to modern quantum mechanics. It could form spontaneously like this with an extremely minisicule probability. One may not know the exact probability but it is small enough defined by our modern theories that we never have to even think of its possibility. Not a single person on earth, I dare, would attach even a modicum of credence to this idea if someone told you that a particular phone completely formed by chance without design.
Supernatural theories on the other hand seem to be obscure. There seems to be no predictive or explanatory power attached to them, and the process of how a supernatural being operates or creates the world that we see today or does literally anything is not even well defined under theism. God’s nature is completely obscure, opaque, and arguably unfalsifiable.
And yet, many people would still consider it more plausible for God to exist than the computer example mentioned above. But we at the very least know that the computer forming by currently known physics is possible. We don’t know this in the case of god. Shouldn’t something without evidence automatically be included in the set of the least implausible theories than something that does have a known possibility of occurring?

Isn't it because there is no rational explanation that the label 'supernatural' is used? Some unexplained phenomenon is called 'supernatural', and when it is understood it is called 'natural' as if in our conceit nature needs our permission.

I think the question is not well formulated. If you ask: Shouldn’t something without evidence automatically be included in the set of the least implausible theories than something that does have a known possibility of occurring? We have no evidence that Napoleon used the toilet when he was in Moscow. Still, I think it is plausible. You have to be more precise what you are comparing.

"But we at the very least know that the computer forming by currently known physics is possible." That's a HUGE stretch...

Yes. However, you must bear in mind that even the most deeply routed, sorry, rooted beliefs need not be the result of reasoning from evidence. On the contrary, many people hold passionate convictions about all kinds of matters that cannot be justified rationally.

There are more than 100 questions on this SE about the Hiddenness of God, yet there are none about the Hiddenness of Human Rationality...

@shindemo curses, foiled again! You’ve condemned me to a  fate of typing endless stupid answers. I’m not sure I can face it!

As rationality cannot be justified, and no justifications pass Munchausen's Trilemma, none of our beliefs are ever "justified".


Shouldn’t something without evidence automatically be included in the set of the least implausible theories than something that does have a known possibility of occurring?

The formation of an iPhone 14 by chance is not a known possibility. It has never been observed or documented. While it may be possible in principle to calculate a probability for such an event using quantum mechanics, this is not equivalent to knowing it’s a genuine possibility. It remains a theoretical prediction contingent on the validity of the theory itself, which could very well turn out to be incorrect. In fact, we know that quantum mechanics (QM) and general relativity (GR) require reconciliation, and certain phenomena—such as consciousness—remain unaccounted for by current physical theories. Thus, QM is not universally or completely true.
The idea of an iPhone 14 forming by chance is better described as a hypothetical possibility, not a known one.

Supernatural theories on the other hand seem to be obscure. There seems to be no predictive or explanatory power attached to them,  and the process of how a supernatural being operates or creates the world that we see today or does literally anything is not even well defined under theism.

A more nuanced view would require evaluating supernatural hypotheses on a case-by-case basis. Some supernatural hypotheses do claim to make predictions. For example, within the traditions of witchcraft and occultism, you can find numerous purported testable predictions if you’re willing to delve deeply enough into their conceptual frameworks (which is a big if).

God’s nature is completely obscure, opaque, and arguably unfalsifiable.

This assessment seems valid unless God were to reveal himself and provide insights into his nature to an individual. However, such a scenario ventures into the realm of mysticism. So, again, if you are willing to delve deeply enough into any mystical tradition, you may potentially encounter many purported testable predictions (which is, once again, a big if).

Shoudn’t the obscurantism of the supernatural automatically [make us] deem it extremely implausible?

It depends on what is meant by the word supernatural. If the word is used in an extremely vague manner, without specifying any concrete details, then being skeptical of the "supernatural" would be equivalent to being skeptical of "abcdrastrakrol." We wouldn’t even know what the word means in the first place, so skepticism toward an incomprehensible concept is the reasonable default. In that case, yes.
However, this doesn’t rule out the possibility that one could dig deeper into a tradition falling under the general umbrella of "supernatural" and eventually arrive at more concrete, less vague concepts and potentially testable theoretical predictions. I’ve already listed general categories such as witchcraft, occultism, and mysticism. I haven’t personally delved into any of them, so I cannot speak from personal experience. However, I’m open-minded enough not to rule out in advance the possibility that more concrete definitions, practices, and testable predictions could emerge if someone were to seriously research and engage deeply with one specific tradition. In this case, my answer would be, "I don’t know, maybe yes, maybe not."

Follow-up questions from comments

Is this a yes, or a no?

It's a "It's complicated, it depends, maybe yes, maybe not, I don't know."
